# When I right click while in edit mode, the context menu doesn't appear

Tags: interface

Just to clarify, my select is set to left mouse button.
All keybinds are default.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

go to Edit>Preferences>Keymap
In the searchbox type: Call menu
Then have a look in the search results for "Mesh Call Menu". And check what key you have assigned for it. Should be "Right Mouse" if you want it like this.
[image: see picture]